# Why is dropping an index on MyISAM table so slow?

Tags: mysql, performance

Why is dropping an index on MyISAM table so slow? I can't imagine I'd have social network with 700m records & dropping index.

There are only one-column indexes, all of them are fulltext (I need to switch to normal index as InnoDB don't like fulltext)

DROP INDEX

```
mysql> DROP INDEX `post_text` ON phpbb_posts;
Query OK, 251171 rows affected (7 min 35.04 sec)
Records: 251171  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

however, ALTER TABLE is faster than that DROP?

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE phpbb_posts DROP INDEX `post_content`;
Query OK, 251182 rows affected (1 min 45.06 sec)
Records: 251182  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> ALTER TABLE phpbb_posts DROP INDEX `post_subject`;
Query OK, 251188 rows affected (1 min 32.55 sec)
Records: 251188  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

There is even a [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=2364) for it but no valid solution.

Questions:

- Why is DROP INDEX slower than ALTER TABLE?
- Why is dropping the index so slow on such a small table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to micromanage the dropping of the index, why not automate yourself ?

```
CREATE TABLE phpbb_posts_new LIKE phpbb_posts;
ALTER TABLE phpbb_posts_new DROP INDEX post_text;
ALTER TABLE phpbb_posts_new DISABLE KEYS;
INSERT INTO phpbb_posts_new SELECT * FROM phpbb_posts;
ALTER TABLE phpbb_posts_new ENABLE KEYS;
ALTER TABLE phpbb_posts RENAME phpbb_posts_old;
ALTER TABLE phpbb_posts_new RENAME phpbb_posts;
DROP TABLE phpbb_posts_old;
```

This is essentially what doing the ALTER TABLE would do 'under the hood'

Doing it this way will let you see the timing of each of these internal steps.

**UPDATE 2011-10-10 14:08 EDT**

I actually researched this personally. [I remember complaining to MySQL about how slow adding indexes were when adding or dropping and suggested how they can fix it. That was back in October 2006](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/202489).

[Then, suddenly, out of nowhere, someone asked about this same issue on May 12, 2011.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/does-mysql-still-handle-indexes-in-this-way/2697#2697) The person posting the question ([JIStone](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1682/jistone)) even referenced my original post to MySQL. I did not realize it, until about 7 minutes later, that I was actually addressing my own 5-year-old post.

Comment: Nice find. Can I ask, where did you find this?

Comment: I updated my answer how I learned this.

Comment: I didn'T even know you're the owner of this report.

Comment: Wouldn't you know it? Today is Oct 10, 2011 and I posted my suggestion to MySQL Oct 10, 2006, Exactly five years ago today !!!

Answer (score 2):

Why? Because the developers made mistakes?! Why should there be a bug report when it isn't a bug- So wait until it got fixed or fix it yourself- As you even have a workaround you can live with it.

But the proper answer would be that `DROP INDEX` doesn't lock the table while executing. And therefore it takes more time to allow reading and writing while dropping- And `ALTER TABLE` locks the table and so can concentrate on the dropping process.

Comment: Huh, the bug exists from 2006. Do you think somebody will fix it?

Comment: @genesis-φ Do you think they won't?

Comment: I'm not sure. Thanks for edit though